# using a sync adapter to maintain a incoming feed

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, contentobserver

I can't find a specific example of this, though it seems like it would be a fairly well-tread path, and one of the primary purposes of a sync adapter. I have implemented most of this but still have some problems to figure out. Here is my basic strategy right now

PerformSync

- Figure out the last item stored locally
- if there are no local items, pull new items to a certain maximum size
- if there are local items, pull new items until reaching local items
- delete items over the maximum item size

I have a list adapter with a content observer that should reflect the synced information.

**Question:**
If all of this is sound,  my current dilemma is how an when to delete items from the database. I am assuming I should refrain from any deletions while the content is in use, but in my sync adapter, how do I know if the data is currently being observed? (static map of observers?)

**Supplemental:**
Beyond that, I would love to have some examples of this in action, so I can anticipate other problems. I know about the google IO talk, it has some great high level philosophy, but specifics would do wonders for many non-guru devs.

I would think this is an extremely valuable function that all Android advocates would want to be done, and done right, as the sync adapter presents one of the most desirable features of Android, and can only help to increase the userbase, helping all of us.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion: maybe sync adapter should only add new items but not delete old ones and deletions should be done by the app.

Note: it seems that in Android Gmail deletions are happening while app is showing emails. Try deleting/archiving message in web-gmail and then menu-Refresh in Android: sync will run in the background and then message will be gone without any notification. So it seems to be acceptable.

**Update:**

Maybe your sync adapter should check if your activity is active and if not delete old items. How to check if your activity is active: http://www.mannaz.at/codebase/android-activity-foreground-surveillance/

Comment: Thought of your suggestion before. Only problem with that is if they happen to not open the app for a while, it will just be endlessly filling the database. That still might be the best solution though for all practical purposes.

Comment: Apparently gmail doesn't use a content observer to instantly refresh the list, otherwise the deletions would occur without having to hit refresh. That is good info though, thanks, totally forgot to look at gmail.